# VS Code not linking keyword "this" to current javascript object?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, javascript-intellisense, this

In VS Code, i'm making a js file with this piece of code

```
const ObjectX = {
      abc(){

      },
      xyz(){
           this.abc()
      },
}
```

And when I'm typing `this.` and press `Ctrl + space` I expect VS Code to suggest me with `abc()` as a member of `this` but it doesn't.

When I type the full line `this.abc()` then press `F2` at definition line to rename `abc()`, VS Code doesn't rename all the calls to `this.abc()` as well.

All 2 facts definitely say that VS Code doesn't link the keyword `this` to current object. This behavior is inconvenient cause another install of VS on another PC do links.

Anyone experienced this can give me a line of configuration to fix VS Code ?

---

PS1: This is just bad coding experience with VS Code,  not the way javascript code works!

PS2: I've tried TypeScript with the same behavior.

PS3: I have intellisense with newest version of VSCode and my `jsconfig.json` looks like this

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "experimentalDecorators": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        ".vscode",
        "library",
        "local",
        "settings",
        "temp"
    ]
}
```

Comment: check out TypeScript to cast objects

Comment: @sonEtLumiere Tried TypeScript. The same behavior.

Comment: It’s by design behavior of typescript. VSCode use ts for js language support, thus the result you see.

Comment: @hackape So why did I see different behavior in another install of VS Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple but hard to find out:

Add this line to `tsconfig.json` of project

```
  "compilerOptions": {
     ....
    "noImplicitThis": true
     ....
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your file extension? If it is .js it should intellisense this.abc() as javascript.

What does the language mode show when the file is open under VS.Code. Language mode is displayed at the bottom right corner. If it is not showing "JavaScript" as language mode you can click on it and change to JavaScript. Default is AutoDetect.
You can also type Ctrl-K and then M keys to bring up language mode.

See here : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_changing-the-language-for-the-selected-file

Comment: I save code in file extension = ".js". Yes. It should but it doesn't. That's why I post a question here :)

Comment: Check the language mode, as I edited my answer above.

Comment: Thanks but it's not "AutoDetect" but "javascript" already

Comment: There are 3 settings files that control that I can find: Default settings, User settings and workspace settings. You can check each and compare them with the one on the other installation. Open default settings file: View->Command Pallette->Preferences:Open Default Settings (JSON). Open user settings file: View->Command Pallette->Preferences:Open Settings (JSON), and Open workspace settings file: View->Command Pallette->Preferences:Open Workspace Settings (JSON).

Comment: Thanks so much for this deep digging. I will try to compare them!